# Audi 2001 A6 security system preventing car from starting

Tags: alarm, audi

My father-in-law has an Audi A6 and randomly the security system prevents the car from starting, you can open the doors with the remote, but the car won't start.

The only remedy is to unlock the door with the key, sitting for 10 minutes, and then the alarm resets.

Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: When the car won't start, what happens exactly? Does the alarm system appear to be still engaged (e.g., red warning light blinking)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the mechanic missed the last code on the list when he looked at the computer. It was the camshaft sensor. Thanks anyway, and sorry for taking so long to get back!